# Изменить тип string на string-array

Tags: android, строки

Данный код сравнивает ответы, введеные в EditText, с ответами из условия и выделять поля: при правильном ответе - зеленым, при не правильном -красным. Если все ответы верны, переходить на новое активити. Если нет, то нет.

Хочу расширить вероятность ответов вводимых пользователем, в связи с этим, вижу необходимость изменить string на string-array, но как сделать проверку не совсем понимаю.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private boolean isValid(final EditText source, final String expected) {
    String actual = source.getText().toString();
    return expected.equals(actual);
}

private void visualizeValidity(final EditText source, final boolean isValid) {
    int backgroundColor = (isValid) ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED;
    source.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
}

private boolean checkEditText(final EditText source, final String expected) {
    boolean valid = isValid(source, expected);
    visualizeValidity(source, valid);

    return valid;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText carOneText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.car1);
    final EditText carTwoText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.car2);
    final EditText carThreeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.car3);

    Button buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck);

    buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean allTextsValid = (
                    checkEditText(carOneText, getString(R.string.maserati) &
                            checkEditText(carTwoText, getString(R.string.mercedes) &
                            checkEditText(carThreeText, getString(R.string.bmw)
            );

            if (allTextsValid) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });

}
}
```

string-array, в который поместил варианты к слову maserati, как мне его добавить в этот код, вместо R.string.maserati? Чтобы он осуществлял проверку вариантов из этого массива

```
<string-array name="maseratiArr">
        <item>maserati</item>
        <item>Maserati</item>
        <item>maaserati</item>
        <item>maserrati</item>
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй использовать обычный массив строк:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] maseratiArr = res.getStringArray(R.array.maseratiArr);

// Имена ресурсов правильнее записывать таким образом: maserati_array
```

Проверку наличия строки в массиве осуществить перебором:

```
public boolean checkArray (String[] array, String input) {
   boolean valid = false;
   for(String item: array) {
       if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
          valid = true;
          break;
       }
   return valid;
}
```

Потом проверяешь

```
if(checkArray(maseratiArr, carOneText.getText().toString()) {
    // В массиве есть такая строка
} else {
    // В массиве нет такой строки
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Это обычный поиск строки в массиве, тут много вариантов можно придумать.

#### Не самый оптимальный

```
private boolean checkEditText(EditText source, int expectedArrayRes) {
    boolean valid = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(expectedArrayRes))
            .contains(source.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
    visualizeValidity(source, valid);
    return valid;
}

где-нибудь в коде: checkEditText(catOneText, R.array.maseratiArr);
```

#### Чуть получше

```
private Set<String> mMaseratiSet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mMaseratiSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.maseratiArr)));
}

private boolean checkEditText(EditText source, Set<String> expected) {
    boolean valid = expected.contains(source.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
    visualizeValidity(source, valid);
    return valid;
}

где-нибудь в коде: checkEditText(catOneText, mMaseratiSet);
```

Но если `maseratiArr` переведен на несколько языков, то нужно следить, чтобы при смене языка системы во время работы приложения, правильно обновлялся `mMaseratiSet`.